# How to change background color of cell based on other cell value by VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have two columns A and B in an excel sheet.
A column is the drop down list that contains "Yes" and "No".
And I would like to change the color of B cell that base on text value of A cell from drop down list.
For example, if I select "Yes" in A1 cell than the B1 cell should show Green color. A2, A3... etc.

I am not a programmer so I am really noob at VBA coading. Conditional Formation also have a problem for this case.

If anyone have an answer for this, That would be my pleasure.

Comment: Did you atempt to do something already? If so, post your code. Try using `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)` this Sub will occur every time data in Worksheet is changed.

Comment: You say conditional formatting has a problem for this case but it should be able to do exactly what you need given proper usage.

Comment: `Sub RowFormat()
Dim A As Range
For Each A In Range("A1:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
If Not IsError(A) Then
    If A.Value = "Yes" Then
        Range("B" & C.Row & ":BB" & C.Row).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
    Else
        Range("B" & C.Row & ":BB" & C.Row).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
    End If
End If
Next A
End Sub`

Comment: Hi Zerk,
I tried with Conditional Formatting. By not really ok for me.
If you have any suggestion pls!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Made some changes in your code.

```
Sub RowFormat()
    Dim A As Range
    For Each A In Range("A1:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
        If Not IsError(A) Then
            If A.Value = "Yes" Then
                A.Offset(0, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
            ElseIf A.Value = "No" Then
                A.Offset(0, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            Else
                A.Offset(0, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
            End If
        End If
    Next A
End Sub
```

Using Conditional Formatting.

For "Yes" use `=A1="Yes"`,
for "No" use `=A1="No"` and format apply formatting accordingly.

[image]

***EDIT :***

If you are using **Worksheet_Change**  event then use below code.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Intersect(Target, Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub 'check for range
    If Target.Value = "Yes" Then 'check if yes
        Target.Offset(0, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
    ElseIf Target.Value = "No" Then 'check if no
        Target.Offset(0, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    Else
        Target.Offset(0, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I changed 
`Sub RowFormat()`
to
`Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)`
and it's work.
Thank @Mrig

Comment: @PhyoHtetHlaing - See edit in answer. For `Worksheet_Change` you can check only for the cell changed and not the whole range.

Answer (score 0):

To use conditional formatting

Select Column B,
Click Conditional Format >

Highlight Cells Rules >

Equal Too > Type "Yes"

On the drop down to the right select Custom,

choose your formatting,

Repeat the process again for "No"

There will be many easier to follow methods shown with a quick google search...